# Checking the format of a string

Tags: c++, std

I have a vector of strings im working trought, and i need to check how the string is formated. 
Im using sscanf in the rest of the function and i need something like this.

```
if (format("%f,%f,%f")) {
  // Do someting
} else if (format("%d,%d")) {
  // Do something else
} else {
  // Do something
}
```

Is this possible using sscanf or something else from std?

Comment: should probably use a regex library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use *tr1* then `std::tr1::regex` is the way to go.. take a look [here](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html).

Comment: or if you can use C++11 you can use `std::regex`, without the tr1.